# SQL Listagg syntax

Tags: sql, listagg

I am using an SQL query with a listagg function to aggregate phone numbers from multiple rows into 1 column. However I get the same phone numbers multiple times in the list like: 
[ phone1 / phone1 / phone1 / phone2 / phone2 / phone2 / phone3 / phone3 / phone3 ]

```
select 
link.adr
--, (Select a.Descr from thr_adr_lnk_type a where link.type = a.type) Address_Type
, t.trader 
, t.trader_descr
, d.third
, d.name_i
, d.f_city
, d.country_descr
, d.def_phone
, d.def_mail
, d.f_street Third_Street
,adrcon.first_name
,adrcon.last_name
, listagg(adrph.formated_phone_nr, '/' ) within group (order by link.adr)
,adrdet.street Contact_Street
,adrdet.post_code
,adrdet.city
,adrdet.country
,adrml.email


from tra_contract c join 
tra_trader t on t.trader = c.trader_transact join
thr_v_third d on d.third = c.supplier OR d.third = c.customer
left join thr_adr_lnk link on link.third = d.third 
left join adr_contact adrcon on adrcon.adr = link.adr left join
adr_address_det adrdet on adrdet.adr = link.adr join
adr_v_phones adrph on adrph.adr = adrcon.adr and adrph.contact = adrcon.contact and adrph.type = link.type
left join adr_mail adrml on adrml.adr = adrcon.adr and adrml.contact = adrcon.contact and adrml.deflt = 1 and adrcon.contact = adrml.contact


where t.trader = '32'
group by link.adr
, t.trader 
, t.trader_descr
, d.third
, d.name_i
, d.f_city
, d.country_descr
, d.def_phone
, d.def_mail
, d.f_street 
,adrcon.first_name
,adrcon.last_name
,adrdet.street 
,adrdet.post_code
,adrdet.city
,adrdet.country
,adrml.email



order by link.adr
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify - [mcve].

Comment: You seem to be joining and grouping only to get concatenated contact data. I would rather ditch all joins and group by and move the listagg logic to select clause.